# Error ORA-00600 in select table in Oracle dblink

Tags: oracle, dblink

I created an Oracle Dblink to access SQLServer tables.
I can see the tables/views I have access.

[image]

But when I execute a select, it returns ORA-00600.

[image]

My dblink create command:

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK SQLREQUERIM CONNECT TO my_user IDENTIFIED BY "myPassword" USING 'MSSQLREQUERIM';
```

My tnsnames.ora file

```
MSSQLREQUERIM =
  (DESCRIPTION=
    (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=myOracleHost)(PORT=1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=MSSQLREQUERIM))
    (HS=OK)
  )
```

My listener.ora file

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
 (SID_LIST =
   (SID_DESC=
     (SID_NAME=MSSQLREQUERIM)
     (ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1)
     (PROGRAM=dg4odbc)
   )
 )
```

My odbc.ini

```
[ODBC Data Sources]
MSSQLREQUERIM = MSSQL Server

[MSSQLREQUERIM]
Driver=/usr/lib64/libtdsodbc.so.0
Description     = MSSQL Server
Trace           = No
Server          = mySQLServerHost
Database        = REQUERIM
Port            = 60472
TDS_Version     = 7.2
```

My iniMYSQLREQUERIM.ora file

```
HS_FDS_CONNECT_INFO = MSSQLREQUERIM
HS_FDS_TRACE_LEVEL = DEBUG
HS_FDS_SHAREABLE_NAME = /usr/lib64/libodbc.so
set ODBCINI=/etc/odbc.ini
```

Comment: ORA-00600 means you need to contact Oracle support

Comment: Specifically, see [this Oracle Support article](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/1224783_1.html) - I think the problem is that some DB link drivers translate large text fields in SQL Server as LONG datatype, which has many limitations in Oracle - like only 1 is allowed per table. Instead of `select *`, try only selecting certain columns.

Comment: Thanks kfinity, 
you killed the charade

Answer (score -1):

The error was due to some table columns having types (text) that are incompatible with Oracle. Suppressing these columns the search worked.